# Do not go to full screen application when switching back to workspace

Tags: unity, workspaces

Workspace 1: Youtube on full screen. Terminal window in front of it (relatively transparent so I can see through it).
Workspace 2: Another browser open.

I am in Workspace one, with the terminal in front of the full screen youtube video. I switch to workspace two to check something on google. When I switch back to workspace one, instead of having the terminal in front, I have the full screen video. How can I avoid that?

Edit: Same problem happens if I have Terminal Always on Top

Comment: Do you really need this terminal in front of the full screen Youtube video? If you need both the video and the terminal on the same screen, then working with the normal browser window and eventually the video enlarged in theater mode functionally will be equally good.

Comment: I tested myself, and I do not have the issue with full screen Youtube and Gnome-terminal in front. If I leave with the terminal in front, it stays that way when returning (Gnome Shell on Ubuntu 19.04). It thus might be an issue specific to Unity desktop, and in particular its window manager, Compiz.